# Sugar.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, sugar.js

I have this lngArr:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "18746": 20.75,
            "id": "18746",
            "impression": 20.75
        },
        "name": "Missing"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18748": 77.91,
            "id": "18748",
            "impression": 77.91
        },
        "name": "English"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18749": 0.02,
            "id": "18749",
            "impression": 0.02
        },
        "name": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18751": 0.31,
            "id": "18751",
            "impression": 0.31
        },
        "name": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18753": 0.01,
            "id": "18753",
            "impression": 0.01
        },
        "name": "Chinese"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18757": 0.01,
            "id": "18757",
            "impression": 0.01
        },
        "name": "Dutch"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18760": 0.01,
            "id": "18760",
            "impression": 0.01
        },
        "name": "French"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18763": 0.69,
            "id": "18763",
            "impression": 0.69
        },
        "name": "Hebrew"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18764": 0.08,
            "id": "18764",
            "impression": 0.08
        },
        "name": "Hindi"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18771": 0.2,
            "id": "18771",
            "impression": 0.2
        },
        "name": "Korean"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18772": 0.01,
            "id": "18772",
            "impression": 0.01
        },
        "name": "Latvian"
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "18786": 0.01,
            "id": "18786",
            "impression": 0.01
        },
        "name": "Turkish"
    }
]
```

and here is my sorting code:

```
lngArr.sortBy(function(lng) {
                return -lng.data.impression;
            });
```

I don't know why it is not working. [here is the documentation](http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/sortBy).

Comment: So, *how* does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/sortBy) might be a bit unclear when stating that `Array` is returned, but the [source](https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar/blob/master/lib/array.js#L967) clears this up:

A **new** (sorted) array is returned.

So you likely want to do

```
lngArr = lngArr.sortBy(function(lng) {
    return -lng.data.impression;
});
```

Comment: it is doing something now, cause the result is different, but still it is not sorting (and not sorting descendant) .

Comment: Works well for me. Output order is `English Missing Hebrew Arabic Korean Spanish …`. Please be more specific.

Comment: Just put the snippet in the console at the sugar.js website. Please make a fiddle that demonstrates your problem.